# Why does my F# function result in an out of bounds error when using Array.iter?

Tags: .net, arrays, f#

I have a function where Array.iter is used to print the 4th element of a nested array (z) after applying a function. I am feeding in a long string delimited by '\n' and then (nested) delimitation of '"'. It seems to iterate through to beyond the end of the higher-level array (y).

```
let digestMDtest (x : string) =
    let y = x.Split '\n' |> Array.tail
    let mapMD (x : string) =
        let z = x.Split '"'
        printfn "%s" z.[3]
    Array.iter mapMD y
```

I am receiving the error, you can see the last 3 timestamps that are part of the data I am feeding in, "2016-04-15T15:59:00-04:00" is the last element, it seems to be going beyond it.

```
2016-04-15T15:57:00-04:00
2016-04-15T15:58:00-04:00
2016-04-15T15:59:00-04:00
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at FSI_0002.mapMD@69-1(String x) in C:\OneDrive\FSMDC.barchart.fsx:line 70
   at FSI_0002.digestMDtest(String x) in C:\OneDrive\FMDC.barchart.fsx:line 72
```

It seems to me the Array.iter function is attempting to iterate over an Array element that is beyond the end of the array. Why would it do this? I can only assume Array.tail has something to do with it; maybe Array.iter is using the original size of the array instead of the current size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your written description of your input data, I created an example setup like this (please let me know if I've misinterpreted your description!):

```
let data = "\"2016-04-15T15:57:00-04:00\"\n\"2016-04-15T15:58:00-04:00\"\n\"2016-04-15T15:59:00-04:00\""
```

Assuming that my data approximately matches yours, you're going to skip the first value and then `Array.iter` over the remaining two values:

```
"2016-04-15T15:58:00-04:00"
"2016-04-15T15:59:00-04:00"
```

You then call this function on each element:

```
let mapMD (x : string) =
    let z = x.Split '"'
    printfn "%s" z.[3]
```

Calling `Split` on these strings gives a result that looks like this:

```
[|"", date, ""|]
```

You index element `.[3]` from this array but there are only 3 elements so this will trigger an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on every element.

Indexing elements is *generally speaking* not a good pattern in functional programming, using a pattern where you can make the intent more explicit is generally better.

As an example, if I were trying to extract the date string in this case, I would do it like this:

```
let mapMD (x : string) =
    match x.Split '"' with
    |[|_; date; _|] -> printfn "%s" date
    |_ -> raise <| FormatException("Invalid Date String Format")
```

You can see that here, the pattern match concisely describes the expected format of the string array.

Comment: My data set after x.Split has about 9 elements, so it is not going beyond the bounds of that. Each element of data I pass into mapMD is in this form `""FRE","9484","103843,"2016-04-15T15:58:00-04:00","54.998","6554""`

Comment: @Mike if you run your `mapMD` function on the input string you provided, it returns `9484`.  Since that works without any exception, the exception you are seeing can only be a result of you passing in a string of the wrong format.  I would recommend looking at the values of `y` since one of those values must not be of the format you supplied above.

Answer (score 2):

The `IndexOutOfRange` exception is not connected with `Array.iter`, but rather with indexing into a different array - specifically at line 70, the expression `z.[3]`.

Apparently you have a line that has fewer than four quote-delimited parts.

---

As a side note, I would recommend using `Seq.skip` and `Seq.iter` instead of `Array.tail` and `Array.iter` respectively. That `Array.tail` call will reallocate a whole new array, which may get expensive.

```
let digestMDtest (x : string) =
    x.Split '\n' 
    |> Seq.skip 1
    |> Seq.iter (fun (x : string) ->
        let z = x.Split '"'
        printfn "%s" z.[3] )
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with Seq.skip, however, I don't see how it can be the nested-array as it has enough data points: I have an array of data and each element is formatted as: `""FRE","9484","103843,"2016-04-15T15:58:00-04:00","54.998","6554""`